# Ignoring HTML tags in MySQL search

Tags: mysql, wordpress, relevanssi

I have a WordPress site using a search plugin called Relevanssi. I'm still working on configuring the search functionality as best as I can; am running into one problem still. Relevanssi's search is MySQL based; which (to my knowledge) means that Relevanssi searches the database tables when a query is made on the front-end of my site.

The issue I have (and I've contacted Relevanssi's developer about this, who has no idea how to fix this) is that when I search for a sentence, and this sentence includes italicized or bolded text in the actual WordPress page, Relevanssi returns a "No Results Found" page.

Example: If I search for, "described in the course as if it has two parts" I get no results, because the actual phrase on the website is, "described in the course *as if* it has two parts" -- the "as if" is in italics.

So I think what's happening is that the Relevanssi MySQL-based search cannot find this example phrase, because the code for this phrase looks like this: `described in the course <i>as if</i> it has two parts`

So the search gets "hung up" on the `<i>` (and other HTML) tags.

I'm wondering now if anyone can help me set up the search function so that it ignores the `<i>` tags when a query is made? In other words, set it up in a way where it doesn't matter whether a search result would have italics in it.

Comment: The simplest way would be to have an extra field in your table(s)  in which you could store the plain text without any html code and the plugin would search these fields instead of the original content.

Comment: Thanks. No idea if that's possible...

Comment: Removing tags or making this plugin to work on another field?

Comment: a long shot... but: you could split up the search term so you actually search for each single word: ´select... where `content` LIKE '%hello%' AND `content` LIKE '%world%' . that would bypass any tags

Comment: @Shadow: Removing the tags I think I could handle. As far as having "an extra field" in my table to store the plain text, then have Relevanssi search those tables instead - no idea how I'd get that set up. Looking for something simple if at all possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know thus plugin, so I cannot help you with that. But my guess is that you can configure this plugin to search specific fields only.

Comment: Quick read on the plugin's website lead to this option: Custom MySQL columns to index (Premium only) . If you have a premium version, this is your answer.

Comment: Cool! Thank you. I'll get in touch with the plugin developer in regards to this!

Comment: I haven't resolved this issue yet. Using Relevanssi's (premium version) "Custom MySQL columns to index" isn't an option because it's going to double the size of my database and it's already huge. So, still wondering if there's a way to have MySQL ignore or filter out <i>, <em>, <strong> tags, etc. - essentially just skipping them in the search, as if they are invisible. Thank you.